# C - garbage characters even with null terminator, structures

Tags: c, string, struct, character, garbage

So as part of a school assignment I have to create an application to handle the input of various fields using a structure. defined outside of main as following

```
typedef struct stud {
    struct number {
        int studNum;
    } number;
    struct name {
        char firstName[NAME_SIZE];
        char lastName[NAME_SIZE];
    } name;
    struct cellNum {
        int areaCode;
        int prefix;
        int suffix;
    } cellNum;
    struct courses {
        struct fall {
            char className[NAME_SIZE];
            float mark;
        } fall;
        struct winter {
            char className[NAME_SIZE];
            float mark;
        } winter;
    } courses;
} stud;
```

NAME_SIZE is defined as 30

I access the struct as following

```
stud studArray[100]; // max 100 students
stud *studPtr;

for (int i = 0; i < studCount; i++) {
    studPtr = &studArray[i];
    initializeStrings(studPtr[i]);
    getNum(studPtr[i]);
    getName(studPtr[i]);
    getCell(studPtr[i]);
    getCourses(studPtr[i]);
}
```

initializeStrings is where I add the null terminator's

```
void initializeStrings(stud student) {
    student.name.firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0'; 
    student.name.lastName[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
    student.courses.fall.className[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
    student.courses.winter.className[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
}
```

This is now where the problem occurs: in any of my various functions, when I try and access any of the information I write to my string, I get an output of garbage characters that look like a sideways T, but only if i access the data in a different function.

Example: this is the code to get 2 courses and marks

```
void getCourses(stud student) {
    getchar();
    printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Fall 2016: ");
    fgets(student.courses.fall.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);
    fflush(stdin); // suggested by my prof to fix the issue, did nothing

    printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.fall.className, ": ");
    scanf("%f", &student.courses.fall.mark);

    getchar();
    printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Winter 2017: ");
    fgets(student.courses.winter.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);

    printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.winter.className, ": ");
    scanf("%f", &student.courses.winter.mark);
}
```

If I enter helloWorld as a course name, the system correctly prints
    enter mark received for helloWorld

but when I try and print the data from my print function:

```
void printData(stud student) {
// various other values (none of which work)
printf("\t%s\t%s\t%f\n", "Fall2016", student.courses.fall.className, student.courses.fall.mark);
}
```

I get garbage data output ( [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri1xt.jpg) )

Any help/code criticism welcome

EDIT: Thank you Eddiem, and everyone else, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Where is `printData(stud)` being called? I don't see it in code snippet 2.

Comment: in a seperate for loop right below snippet 2

     `for (int i = 0; i < studCount; i++) {
  printData(studPtr[i]);
 }`

This allows 2 or more students to be entered before the final table is printed

Comment: You are passing a `struct` to `initializeStrings` and other `struct` members to functions which do not find their way back, because you only pass a copy. You could initialise your structs with `stud studArray[100] = {0};`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior

Comment: Well laid out question. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't really make sense.  First, why not pass `stud*` pointers to each of the functions you're calling below?  Regardless, the way you have it here, you're initializing `studPtr` to point to a particular element in the `studArray` array, but then still indexing `i` into that pointer.  You could probably pass `studPtr[0]`, but that's just weird.

Original code:

```
stud studArray[100]; // max 100 students
stud *studPtr;

for (int i = 0; i < studCount; i++) {
    studPtr = &studArray[i];
    initializeStrings(studPtr[i]);
    getNum(studPtr[i]);
    getName(studPtr[i]);
    getCell(studPtr[i]);
    getCourses(studPtr[i]);
}
```

I would suggest modifications like the following:

```
void initializeStrings(stud *student) {
    student->name.firstName[NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0'; 
    student->name.lastName[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
    student->courses.fall.className[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
    student->courses.winter.className[NAME_SIZE -1] = '\0';
}
```

These modifications would need to be made to each if the functions that currently take a `stud` parameter.  Then, change your loop initialization to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studCount; i++) {
    initializeStrings(&studArray[i]);
    getNum(&studArray[i]);
    getName(&studArray[i]);
    getCell(&studArray[i]);
    getCourses(&studArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is not right:

```
studPtr = &studArray[i];
initializeStrings(studPtr[i]);
```

Say you want to access the third element of your array, so `i` is 3. This gives you an offset to that third entry:

```
studPtr = &studArray[i];
```

Now you use an index with that....

```
initializeStrings(studPtr[i]);
```

So you're accessing 3 elements further than the third one you're already at; i.e. element 6. You can see you're going to step off the end of the array, or access elements you haven't initialised.

So use *either*:

```
studPtr = &studArray[i];
initializeStrings(studPtr);
```

or

```
initializeStrings(&studArray[i]);
```

Those two amount to the same thing, and point at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not passing by reference (aka using pointers). If you don't use pointers then functions like `getCourses` modify temporary data instead of the data directly. Thus, the junk values in the original data are never removed.

Change

```
void getCourses(stud student) { // no pointer = copy data to temporary memory, original data is unmodified in this function.
getchar();
printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Fall 2016: ");
fgets(student.courses.fall.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);
fflush(stdin); // suggested by my prof to fix the issue, did nothing

printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.fall.className, ": ");
scanf("%f", &student.courses.fall.mark);

getchar();
printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Winter 2017: ");
fgets(student.courses.winter.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);

printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.winter.className, ": ");
scanf("%f", &student.courses.winter.mark);
}
```

To

```
void getCourses(stud *student) { // notice the pointer used. Original data is to be modified.
getchar();
printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Fall 2016: ");
fgets(student->courses.fall.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);
fflush(stdin); // suggested by my prof to fix the issue, did nothing

printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.fall.className, ": ");
scanf("%f", &student->courses.fall.mark);

getchar();
printf("\n%s", "Enter Course name - Winter 2017: ");
fgets(student->courses.winter.className, NAME_SIZE - 1, stdin);

printf("\n%s%s%s", "Enter mark received for ", student.courses.winter.className, ": ");
scanf("%f", &student->courses.winter.mark);
}
```

Further more, you must modify your for loop to handle the pointers. Ie, change `getCourses(studPtr[i]);` to `getCourses(&studPtr[i]);`